# Building a list of maps from values combinations in Groovy

Tags: groovy, combinations

I would like to transform a HashMap containing List of values to produce all combination with single values.

Example

```
hm = [x : [1,2], y : ['a','b'] ]
```

Expected result is

```
res = [ [x: 1, y : 'a'],
        [x: 1, y : 'b'],
        [x: 2, y : 'a'], 
        [x: 2, y : 'b']   
]
```

Thus far I come up with this apprach

```
println hm.values().combinations().collect{[x:it[0],y:it[1]]}

[[x:1, y:a], [x:2, y:a], [x:1, y:b], [x:2, y:b]]
```

This works, but depends on the name and number of keys in the HashMap, so for

```
hm = [u : [1,2], w : ['a','b'] , z : ['X','Y']]
```

I must rewrite is to

```
println hm.values().combinations().collect{[u:it[0],w:it[1],z:it[2]]}
```

Is there a general solution for all Key names and number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a closure to `.combinations()` method to transform the current combination. Then you can use `[[a,b,c], [1,2,3]].transpose()` that "zips" values from two lists together (e.g. `[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]]` from the following example) and you can transform the list of such pairs into a map with `.collectEntries()`.

Consider the following example:

```groovy
def hm = [x : [1,2], y : ['a','b'] ]

def combs = hm.values().combinations { args ->
    [hm.keySet().asList(), args].transpose().collectEntries { [(it[0]): it[1]]}
}

combs.each {
    println it
}
```

The output:

```
[x:1, y:a]
[x:2, y:a]
[x:1, y:b]
[x:2, y:b]
```

Now, we can add another key to the input map and the code will work as expected:

```groovy
def hm = [x : [1,2], y : ['a','b'], z: ['X','Y'] ]

def combs = hm.values().combinations { args ->
    [hm.keySet().asList(), args].transpose().collectEntries { [(it[0]): it[1]]}
}

combs.each {
    println it
}
```

The output:

```
[x:1, y:a, z:X]
[x:2, y:a, z:X]
[x:1, y:b, z:X]
[x:2, y:b, z:X]
[x:1, y:a, z:Y]
[x:2, y:a, z:Y]
[x:1, y:b, z:Y]
[x:2, y:b, z:Y]
```

And the final example after making the code even more elegant may look like this:

```groovy
def hm = [z : [2,1], y : ['a','b'], x: ['C','B']]

def values = hm.values()
def keys = hm.keySet().toList()

def map = values.combinations { args ->
    [keys, args].transpose().collectEntries { [(it[0]): it[1]]}
}

println map
```

It prints:

```
[[z:2, y:a, x:C], [z:1, y:a, x:C], [z:2, y:b, x:C], [z:1, y:b, x:C], [z:2, y:a, x:B], [z:1, y:a, x:B], [z:2, y:b, x:B], [z:1, y:b, x:B]]
```

### The order of values and keys

One more comment on keys and values ordering. The default map implementation used by Groovy is `LinkedHashMap` which guarantees the order of entries (the order they got added). It means that:

- `map.values()` returns a `LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues`
- `map.keySet()` returns a `LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet`

In our example, we had to define `keys` variable as `hm.keySet().toList()` only because `transpose()` method expects a list of lists.

Comment: Magic! Let me some time to understand it and/or see if there are other solutions and I'll accept;)

Comment: Very good solution. Really like the way you managed to keep it all declarative!

Comment: How are you guaranteed the order of values in `args` will match the order of values in `keySet().asList()`?   Seems like it's working, I just don't know how, since `keySet()` is unordered, and I think `values()` is too.  Have you tried with key names that aren't alphabetically ordered?

Comment: @billjamesdev good point. `[z : 1, a : ['a','b']]` works fine so probably *both Lists are unordered, but in the same order*(?). @SzymonStepniak have I live with it, or is it something like `SELECT` without `ORDER BY` that can work long fine, but after some RDBM upgrage the expected order may change?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber @billjamesdev The default map implementation used by Groovy is `LinkedHashMap`, so the order of entries defines the order of values and keys. It is also worth mentioning that `hm.values()` returns a `LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues`, and `hm.keySet()` returns a `LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet`. Both guarantee the order (defined by order of entries). If you are looking for a different ordering, you may want to use `TreeMap` with your custom comparator. However, the order of elements in `LinkedHashMap` is deterministic, andso you don't have to worry about any randomness or something.

Comment: Golfing: `...transpose().collectEntries()` since it also accepts a vector as return and the input is already that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a  combinations of keys and combinations of values:

```
def result = []

hm.entrySet().eachCombination { combination ->
    combination.collect{it.value}
    .eachCombination {
        def entry = [:]
        for(int i = 0; i < hm.size(); i++) {
            entry.put(combination[i].key, it[i])
        }
        result << entry
    }

    println result
}
```

Which sets `result` to `[[x:1, y:a], [x:2, y:a], [x:1, y:b], [x:2, y:b]]` fo rthe provided input

The simple logic is: find all combinations of key/value pairs, then for each pair of pairs, combine values keeping the order from original key/value pairs.

This works with a dynamic input map in mind.

Given `hm = [x : [1, 2], y : ['a', 'b'], z: ['e', 'f']]`, it results in:

```
[[x:1, y:a, z:e], 
 [x:2, y:a, z:e], 
 [x:1, y:b, z:e], 
 [x:2, y:b, z:e], 
 [x:1, y:a, z:f], 
 [x:2, y:a, z:f], 
 [x:1, y:b, z:f], 
 [x:2, y:b, z:f]]
```

Comment: Works fine, I'm voting for the *shorter* implementation.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yeah I did it too!